# Automapper - projection with EF generates ugly sql

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, projection, automapper-2

I'm using the    *Project()* on my *IQueryable of "EF Object"* to map it to *IQueryable of "POCO Model"*  in the data layer.
The generated SQL statement has 20 LEFT JOINs to the same table. Has anyone seen this behavior?

The object that is being queried has a nested complex objects.

Comment: At least in my case, it looks like it has to do with the Project. EF generates a clean SQL if I don't go through the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I don't know what to do about it, but I think I understand what the problem is. In short, Entity Framework duplicates joins in certain query structures, and AutoMapper uses those query structures.

When Entity Framework sees `entity.Relationship.Field1` and `entity.Relationship.Field2` in a linq query, it generates a separate join for each field.
for example:

```
from entity in dbSet
select new { entity.Relationship.Field1, entity.Relationship.Field2 }
```

might generate the following sql:

```
SELECT [Extent2].[Field1], [Extent3].[Field2]
FROM EntityTable AS [Extent1]
JOIN RelatedTable AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RelationshipID] = [Extent2].[ID]
JOIN RelatedTable AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[RelationshipID] = [Extent3].[ID]
```

**Normally**, this double-join can be avoided by writing linq like this:

```
from entity in dbSet
let relatedValue = entity.Relationship
select new { relatedValue.Field1, relatedValue.Field2 }
```

Producing:

```
SELECT [Extent2].[Field1], [Extent2].[Field2]
FROM EntityTable AS [Extent1]
JOIN RelatedTable AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RelationshipID] = [Extent2].[ID]
```

**Unfortunately**, you don't have this control in AutoMapper. When using `.Project().To()`, they presumably generate each "select" mapping separately and completely, like in the first example. It's probably possible for them to see which relationships/joins they would want to reuse, but depending on how they build the query up, the `let` syntax might be unavailable to them.

Comment: This workaround solution works for me. And there is a thread discussion about this one. It is you @EnvisionAndDevelop
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/621